# Root name server configuration

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a master and a slave server setup for my network with no internet access. I have been trying to set up a root name server for my own network so that all out of zones queries are handled by the local root name server.
Could any help with the required configuration to setup a root name server.

Thanks

Comment: As your question stands now, no, it's overly broad.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is have your DNS server serve records for the root zone (`.`), and then tell your other DNS servers that that server is it's only root server.  There really is nothing special about root servers (apart from scale, on the Internet).  A zone is a zone.